# life of a GWT remote service

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

We are actually using a single RemoteService class which parses rpc gwt payload to instantiate the current ServerImpl Class to do the work via Reflection.

The question is about performance.

Do you thing the current approach we are using is correct?

Or, by the other hand, would you keep the several instances created alive (using a map...)?.

Guice?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the better solution is using [gwt-dispatch](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=gwt-dispatch&t=GettingStarted) or other. It is easier to maintenance.

Comment: thanks, but the question is more Server side. Keep instances of services implementations alive?

Comment: gwt-dispatch has one class for handling all requests. And internally it call handler for you. Handlers are binded by guice (spring). What I understand yours current solution makes it. Because handlers are injected by guice you can inject whatever you want.